# Implications of a Kurdish Exit from Iraq

Tags: middle-east, kurdistan

How would Kurdish officials deal with the situation following a "Yes" vote in a referendum to exit the Iraqi confederation.

The "Kurdistan" so formed would border four countries: Iraq, Turkey Syria and Iran. All those countries would be hostile to the Kurds and could beseige the country, by preventing both air and ground travel to Kurdistan.

Comment: This appears to be asking what would happen in a hypothetical situation: that an independent Kurdistan is formed (peaceably?) in North Iraq, and then its neighbours choose to beseige it. We don't know what would happen, so any answers would be speculation.

Answer (score 2):

> How would Kurdish officials deal with the situation following a "Yes"
>   vote in a referendum to exit the Iraqi confederation.

The idea is getting more hostile responses day by day. Kurdish officials won't have to deal with that situation as most probably they will have to scrap the process.

[Turkey passed a law](http://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/turkey-warns-kurdish-leaders-vote-parliament-convenes-50040546) in the parliament for military intervention if Kurds go ahead with the referendum.

Comment: Ok, but between Turkey and Iraq, there is also Syria. I think Turkey has not too much to do, what happens in Iraq, but it seems, our media will be still dominated by the Middle East.

Comment: @MorningStar Turkey shares a border with both Syria and Iraq (and also with Iran). In fact, the Kurds claim for those borderlands in _all_ four countries. And this is why all the four are now blocking together against the Kurds.